# How to update a view in a fragment from activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using a boolean to update the views in the fragment.

It is working from the fragment, but there is code in the activity that triggers the boolean but until I go to the fragment manually again, the views don't get an update.

**Activity Code:**

```
    billingClientLifecycle.purchaseUpdateEvent.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {
            Log.d("King", "John it 1$it")
            registerPurchases(it)
            subbed = if (it.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("King", "inside empty")
                false
            } else {
                Log.d("King", "inside not empty")
                true
            }

        }
    })
```

**Fragment Code**

```
if (subbed){
        Log.d("King", "insideifsubbed$subbed")
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
    }else{
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        Log.d("King", "insideelsesubbed$subbed")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a Listener in your `Fragment` so that your `Activity` can send a callback to it every time it wants to update any new information.

For example, you can create

```
interface SubbedUpdateListener {
    fun onSubUpdate(subbed: Boolean)
}
```

and also implement the relevant fields and setter

```
var mSubbedUpdateListener: SubbedUpdateListener? = null; private get
fun setSubbedUpdateListener(subbedUpdateListener: SubbedUpdateListener){
    mSubbedUpdateListener = subbedUpdateListener
}
```

and finally the calling code:

```
billingClientLifecycle.purchaseUpdateEvent.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        Log.d("King", "John it 1$it")
        registerPurchases(it)
        subbed = if (it.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("King", "inside empty")
            false
        } else {
            Log.d("King", "inside not empty")
            true
        }

        if(mSubbedUpdateListener != null){
            mSubbedUpdateListener.onSubUpdate(subbed)
        }
    }
})
```

inside your `Activity`, and when you create the new `Fragment`, inside the `onAttach` or `onCreate` methods, you can use the `context` passed in, which should be your calling `Activity`, cast it to your `Activity` class, and then call `activity.setSubbedUpdateListener(this)` if you use `Fragment` to `implements SubbedUpdateListener`. Otherwise, you could also pass in an anonymous or named instance of the `SubbedUpdateListener`. Inside the implementation, you can then check:

```
override fun onSubUpdate(subbed: Boolean){
    if (subbed){
        Log.d("King", "insideifsubbed$subbed")
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
    }else{
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Log.d("King", "insideelsesubbed$subbed")
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry. Just realised your writing in Kotlin, and I was doing my part of the examples in Java.

Comment: can you edit it to work with kotlin? you mixed java and kotlin both :D

Comment: hmm. isn't it Kotlin now?

Comment: no, the function arguments are different and also the 2nd code you have added

Comment: sorry how about now?

Comment: `Otherwise, you could also pass in an anonymous or named instance of the SubbedUpdateListener.` that doesn't work as well as the onAttach/onCreate variant, onCreate shouldn't be used with retained fragment for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is because fragment already created and no one observe the changes of subbed variable. Make subbed boolean as a live data of boolean type and then set value in activity and observe subbed value in fragment just like that.

### Declare Subbed As

```
val subbed : MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
```

### Activity Code:

```
billingClientLifecycle.purchaseUpdateEvent.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        Log.d("King", "John it 1$it")
        registerPurchases(it)
        subbed.value = if (it.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("King", "inside empty")
            false
        } else {
            Log.d("King", "inside not empty")
            true
        }
    }
})
```

### Fragment Code

```
subbed.observe(requireActivity(), Observer{ subbed ->
    // subbed == true
    if (subbed == true){ 
        Log.d("King", "insideifsubbed$subbed")
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
    }else{
        matchesBinding.homeBasicMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeAccountHoldMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homeTransferMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        matchesBinding.homePaywallMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Log.d("King", "insideelsesubbed$subbed")
    }
}
```

Comment: the fragment code doesn't work, it requires some other code aswell